# Using FullCalendar plugin with HTML Select to narrow down criteria

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I've tried searching but I can't figure out how to do this. I've been modifying the tutorial from [CodebyCody/sjurgis adaptation](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/3c9ad1294b1466d7b910) and adapting it to the custom object that I need to display calendar events for.

What I've got so far is passing through the selected value from the HTML Select/Option into the RemoteAction method in the apex class but I can't figure out how to refresh the calendar when the selected value changes. In this case I want to refresh the calendar as there's different types of Assets.

Let me know if I can provide any more information

Thanks!

**VF Page**

```
    <apex:page showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="false" controller="StarlightAssetBooking" >
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"/>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"/>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"  />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="selection">
            <!--
<apex:selectList id="picklistAssetType" value="{!picklistAssetType}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="displayTableFun(this.value)">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!picklistAssetTypeList}"/>
</apex:selectList> 
-->
            <div>
                <select name="Asset Type" id="inputSelect" class="form-control form-group">
                    <option value ="Teardrop Banners"> Teardrop Banners</option>
                    <option value ="A-Frame Banners"> A-Frame Banners</option>
                </select>
            </div>                  
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel id="fullCalendar">
            <body>             
                <script type="text/javascript">                    
                    function getEventData() {                         // records are retrieved from soql database
                        var picklistAssetType = document.getElementById('inputSelect').value;
                        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.StarlightAssetBooking.eventdata}',  // controller and method names                        
                            picklistAssetType,
                            function(result, event){
                                if (event.status) {
                                    evt =  JSON.parse(result);
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({       // html element and library name
                                        events: evt                     
                                    }) 
                                } else if (event.type === 'exception') { 
                                    console.log(event.message);
                                } else {
                                    console.log(event.message);
                                }
                            }, 
                            {escape: false}
                        );
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        getEventData();
                    });                  

                </script>
                <div id="calendar"></div>
            </body>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class StarlightAssetBooking {
    public string eventsJSON {get;set;}

    //The calendar plugin is expecting dates is a certain format. We can use this string to get it formated correctly    
    static String dtFormat = 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a';

    public String picklistAssetType {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> picklistAssetTypeList {get;set;}     

    public StarlightAssetBooking(){
        picklistAssetTypeList = new List<SelectOption>();
        picklistAssetTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Teardrop Banners','Teardrop Banners'));
        picklistAssetTypeList.add(new SelectOption('Frame Banners','Frame Banners'));
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static string eventdata(String picklistAssetType){
        calEvent[] events = new calEvent[]{}; 

        for(AM_Asset_Allocation__c evnt: [select Id, Name,AM_End_Date__c, AllocationName__c,ID__c,AM_Asset__c,AM_Start_Date__c from AM_Asset_Allocation__c WHERE AssetType__c =:picklistAssetType]){
            DateTime startDT = evnt.AM_Start_Date__c;
            DateTime endDT = evnt.AM_End_Date__c;

            calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();                        
            //myEvent.allDay = true;       
            myEvent.title = evnt.AllocationName__c;                        
            myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.url = '/' + evnt.Id;
            myEvent.className = 'event-assetallocation';            
            events.add(myEvent);
        }

        string jsonEvents = JSON.serialize(events);
        jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('startString','start');
        jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('endString','end');

        return jsonEvents;
    }

    // Class to hold calendar event data
    public class calEvent {        

        public String title {get;set;}
        public Boolean allDay {get;set;}
        public String startString {get;set;}
        public String endString {get;set;}
        public String url {get;set;}
        public String className {get;set;}
    }
}
```